# expansion of matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I would like to invert a square matrix $L$.

One can write it as a sum of two matrices, one containing the diagonal terms ($D$) and the other the off-diagonal ones ($A$).

$$L = D+A$$

I would like to know, under which conditions can one make the following expansion of the inverse of $L$:

$$L^{-1} = (D+A)^{-1} = (D(I+D^{-1}A))^{-1} \approx (I-D^{-1}A)D^{-1} = D^{-1}-D^{-1}AD^{-1}$$

Rephrasing the question, I realise that this somehow implies that the terms in the  off-diagonal part $A$ must be "small", but I do not know how to write that condition formally. When is one allowed to make such an expansion and what would be the error?

Comment: "Smallness" pretty much depends on how much error are you willing to tolerate in the approximation. An easy but very restrictive way out is to restrict the off diagonal elements to be infinitesimals.

Comment: restricting the off diagonal elements to infinitesimals is not an option. how can i actually compute the error i am making when expanding in this manner?

Comment: Compute $(D^{-1}A)^2$ (Given $D^{-1}$ even exists). This matrix is $0$ iff there is no error.

Comment: $D^{-1}$ is guaranteed to exist. Can I interpret you statement as $E = (D^{-1}A)^2$ where $E$ is the error? I expected the error to be a scalar quantity. Perhaps I should take the norm of $E$? Basically, I know for sure that for my particular matrices, this matrix will not be 0 and I want a condition on when I can expand, keeping the error below some value $\epsilon$.

Comment: For matrices, there are many scalar quantities that are referred to as "errors", and the one/s you should take into account naturally depend on what you are trying to achieve (?). Information about the restrictions you impose on the invertible matrices would help as well.

Comment: Well, in practice, the above-mentioned matrices are 6x6 and their elements are complex numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Let me write the matrix in question in the form $L:=D-A$ (instead of $D+A$ to avoid alternating signs). Let $D$ be nonsingular and $\|D^{-1}A\|=:\epsilon<1$ for some operator matrix norm. We can write
$$
L=D(I-D^{-1}A).
$$
Using the Neumann series and with $B:=D^{-1}-D^{-1}AD^{-1}$, we have 
$$
L^{-1}=(I-D^{-1}A)^{-1}D^{-1}=[I+D^{-1}A+(D^{-1}A)^2+\cdots]D^{-1}=B+(D^{-1}A)^2(I-D^{-1}A)^{-1}D^{-1}.
$$
Hence the error can be bounded by using the same norm as
$$
\begin{split}
\|L^{-1}-B\|\leq\|D^{-1}A\|^2\|(I-D^{-1}A)^{-1}\|\|D^{-1}\|
\leq
\frac{\|D^{-1}A\|^2\|D^{-1}\|}{1-\|D^{-1}A\|}=\|D^{-1}\|\frac{\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon}.
\end{split}
$$