# Series expansion of rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series

I work with [input-output analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_model) which involves the use of linear algebra. One central pillar in that field is the invertibility of an $m \times m$ or $n \times n$ real matrix $(I-A)$ in combination with the so-called [Hawkins-Simon condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkins%E2%80%93Simon_condition). For further analysis, it may sometimes be useful to employ the Neumann series expansion such that $(I-A)^{-1} = I + A + A^{2} + ...$, where $A = [A_{ij}] = [0,...,1]$.

With multiple steps in between, the matrix $(I-A)$ is effectively derived from the real $m \times n$ matrix $(C-B)$, where $[B_{ij}], [C_{ij}] \geq 0$. My question is now: Is there, similar to above, a series expansion possible for $(C-B)^{-1}$? What would it be and could you recommend literature on that?

Notes: I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934795/expansion-of-matrix-inverse) on this forum, that such an expansion is possible when $(C-B)$ is square. My question is concerned with the case of $(C-B)$ being rectangular. Also, if a solution is available, are there conditions that allow any conclusions at all as to the solution's uniqueness? And, does it matter if $m > n$ or $m < n$?

Comment: You could try this: $$(C-B)^{-1}=(C(I-C^{-1}B))^{-1}=(I-C^{-1}B)^{-1}C^{-1}=(I+C^{-1}B+(C^{-1}B)^2+...)C^{-1}.$$

Comment: The thing is finding the inverses of those non-square matrices.

Comment: @maximiko What exactly do you mean by the "inverse" of $C - B$ when $C - B$ is rectangular? Are you looking for the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse?

Comment: More generally, I mean any generalized inverse. In my understanding, however, the Moore-Penrose inverse would get closest to what I need, @Ben. I should add that the series expansion of $(I-A)^{-1}$ is in my field typically used to represent different production layers along supply chains. Since $(I-A)$ is derived from $(C-B)$, I wonder if that expansion is possible for the latter expression as well (i.e. for the raw data as opposed to the processed data). As for your comments, Joan, do you have suggestions for how to find these inverses?